# Bookmark a dynamic link in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

I have a link http://myinviteLink.net
but when enter http://myinviteLink.net in chrome url bar, and press enter, it changes into
http://regularLink.net

I do not wish to bookmark http://regularLink.net (we can bookmark using the star button) as only via  http://myinviteLink.net I can enter the website, how should I add the bookmark to http://myinviteLink.net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go ahead and create the bookmark.  After you have saved it, bring up the list of bookmarks it is in, right click on it and edit it.  Manually set it for whatever address you like.

Comment: Simple but Great!

Answer (score 1):

Why not just add the bookmark and then edit it and set the url that you want ?